# Как правильно вывести в order изображения товаров?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно вывести на странице заказа в аккаунте  изображения товаров. Эта функция работает, но если товар был удален то выдает ошибку
`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_image () on bool in`. Товара не существует потому и выдает ошибку.

Что нужно дописать чтобы не выдавало этой ошибки?

Какая здесь должна быть проверка?

```
 <?php   echo $product->get_image('thumbnail'); ?>
```

Comment: `if($product) {echo $product->get_image('thumbnail');}; `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к методу get_image() объекта [WC_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html)

Поэтому если товар удален, то соответственно вызовы его метода не доступны

Нужно добавить также проверку на объект

```
if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
   echo $product->get_image('thumbnail');
}
```